# Javascript Objects, Constructors, only returning final value?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning about objects and constructors so created an object for a book.

It works fine after some tests with one element (book OR author OR pages OR read) but when I add more than 1 it only returns the final value.

For example, the below is only returning `"nope"` when I want it to return the `title, author, pages, read` (as I thought my function `"bookInfo"` declares?

What am I missing here as I've checked my code against some examples and can't see any issues?

```
function Book(title, author, pages, read) {
    this.title = title
    this.author = author
    this.pages = pages
    this.read = read
    this.bookInfo = function() {
        return (title, author, pages, read)
    }

}

const LOTR = new Book('lord of the rings', 'JRR', '366', 'nope');

console.log(LOTR.bookInfo());

// should print 'lord of the rings', 'JRR', '366', 'nope') but only returns 'nope' (or whatever the last value is?)
```

Comment: `(title, author, pages, read)` isn’t a tuple, it’s the comma operator in parentheses. Did you mean `[title, author, pages, read]`?

Comment: @Ry- Note that uses the direct passed parameters, it wont work properly if any of them are changed past the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return the assigned values in an array:

```
this.bookInfo = function() { 
  return [this.title, this.author, this.pages, this.read]; 
}
```

or object:

```
this.bookInfo = function() { 
  return {title:this.title, author:this.author, pages:this.pages, read:this.read}; 
}
```

or string:

```
this.bookInfo = function() { 
  return `${this.title} ${this.author} ${this.pages} ${this.read}`; 
}
```